Generating properly rendered SVGs from Mermaid diagrams in Markdown for Pandoc PDF conversion
I'm trying to convert Markdown files containing Mermaid diagrams to PDF using Pandoc. However, I'm encountering issues with the SVG rendering, similar to those reported here. I've explored two approaches:

Using mermaid-cli:
mmdc -i "path\to\file.md" --outputFormat=svg -o "path\to\file\file-svg.md" -c "path\to\mermaid-config.json"


Using mermaid-filter with Pandoc, as I have explained here.


The problem is that the generated SVGs are not rendered correctly in Inkscape or by rsvg-convert.exe, which Pandoc seems to use.
I've tried using a Mermaid configuration file to disable HTML labels, as suggested here and here:
{
  "flowchart": {
    "htmlLabels": false
  },
  "sequence": {
    "htmlLabels": false
  },
  "gantt": {
    "htmlLabels": false
  },
  "class": {
    "htmlLabels": false
  },
  "state": {
    "htmlLabels": false
  },
  "er": {
    "htmlLabels": false
  }
}

However, this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.
Is it possible to use Mermaid JSON configuration files with either mermaid-cli or mermaid-filter to generate SVGs that can be properly rendered by Inkscape and rsvg-convert.exe? If so, how?
My end goal is to have a reliable process for converting Markdown files with Mermaid diagrams to PDF using Pandoc, ensuring that all diagrams are correctly rendered.
P.S. A relevant discussion here and here.

Doesn't seem to be that many command line options. Can you share the output SVG of a simple drawing that has this issue? And why not convert directly to PNG?

You could give the diagram filter a try. The filter tries to be smart and converts to PNG when the final output is PDF via LaTeX. So it does what @chrwahl suggests.

OK, I think after weeks of struggling with this issue, I have a somewhat working solution and it was much easier than what I had initially anticipated. I mean I was working on some code to parse Markdown, before I released SVG is not the only vectorized format that mmdc can export to, it also exports PDFs! So for those poor soules who end-up on this page, here is my cmd batch script:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Check if a file path is provided
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Please provide a Markdown file path as an argument.
    exit /b 1
)

REM Get the full path, filename, and directory of the input file
set "fullpath=%~f1"
set "filename=%~n1"
set "filedir=%~dp1"
set "scriptdir=%~dp0"

REM Create (or recreate) a temporary folder
set "tempfolder=%filedir%%filename%"
if exist "%tempfolder%" rmdir /s /q "%tempfolder%"
mkdir "%tempfolder%"

REM Run Mermaid-cli to preprocess the Markdown file
echo Processing Markdown file with Mermaid...
call mmdc -i "%fullpath%" --outputFormat=pdf --pdfFit -o "%tempfolder%\%filename%.md"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo Error: Mermaid-cli failed with exit code %errorlevel%
    goto :cleanup
)
echo Mermaid-cli processing complete.

@REM exit /b

REM Change to the temporary directory
echo Changing to temporary directory...
pushd "%tempfolder%"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo Error: Failed to change to temporary directory
    goto :cleanup
)
echo Changed to temporary directory successfully.

REM Convert the processed Markdown to PDF using Pandoc
echo Converting to PDF...
call pandoc "%filename%.md" -f markdown-implicit_figures -o "..\%filename%.pdf"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo Error: Pandoc failed with exit code %errorlevel%
    popd
    goto :cleanup
)
echo PDF conversion complete.

REM Change back to the original directory
echo Changing back to original directory...
popd
echo Changed back to original directory.

:cleanup
REM Clean up the temporary folder
echo Cleaning up...
@REM rmdir /s /q "%tempfolder%"

if exist "%filedir%%filename%.pdf" (
    echo Conversion complete. Output file: %filedir%%filename%.pdf
) else (
    echo Error: PDF file was not created.
)

REM Pause to see any error messages
pause

what this script does in a nutshell:

uses mmdc to preprocess the original Markdown file and export the Mermaid code blocks into PDF
uses Pandoc, that if I am not mistaken uses pdflatex to convert the preprocessed Markdown to PDF.

and if you prefer using mermaid-filter, then change your fences code from
```mermaid
```

to
```{.mermaid format=pdf}
```

and then
pandoc -F "%APPDATA%\npm\mermaid-filter.cmd" input.md -o output.pdf

P.S. A more concise version here.
